# cakephp controller not working; view page not found

Tags: php, cakephp

i installed fresh cakephp. its app controller working fine. but when i write my controller and its view but this result in page not found. My code is given below

```
class PostsController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
```

and create folder named Posts in view folder and over there create index.ctp file as well. but its result in page not found. Please help what may be mistake by me or is there any need to configuration. Thanks

Comment: The code looks fine. Which CakePHP version do you use? What is the filename of your controller? And how do you try to access your controller?

Comment: version 2.4.6 filename PostController.php www.example.com/Post/index

Comment: You should be navigating to posts with an s, as in www.example.com/posts/index (the capitalization doesn't matter on "posts" or "index")

Comment: i tried both posts and Posts but same result

Comment: The file has to be named PostsController.php and you have to access it in the way @Kai mentioned.

Comment: did you go to www.example.com to confirm that you can at least get the homepage to load?  If you've just downloaded CakePHP, you should see their default homepage.

Comment: What is the location of the Posts folder you created? Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and AllowOverride All?

Answer (score 3):

Your controller should be named PostsController.php (ie plural)

Just spotted it, you need to extend `AppController` in CakePHP 2.x, not `Controller`: ie:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
```

Comment: change controller PostsController.php but same result

Comment: See edit to answer above re: extending App Controller

Comment: sorry changes to AppController. but same. is there any need to configure somewhere for routing?

Comment: Is it a 1.3 application which you're upgrading to 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

there might problem apache rewrite module. if you are using WAMP, just put on your rewrite module.